# Suggestions For Running Rails 2 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stack

I have an old Rails 2.0.1/Ruby 1.8.7 app that I need to run in a production environment on Ubuntu 14.04 until it gets finished porting to Rails 4 and I'd like to get some advice on what stack to use.  I've been trying to get it going with nginx 1.7.10 and Passenger 5.0.4 but the Rails app doesn't seem to load and I get 404's.  Same thing is happening for me, though, when going to Passenger 3.0.19 and nginx 1.6.2 or combinations of the above. I also tried Passenger standalone and get the same problem.  The only thing that's worked so far is the Webrick server that comes standard in script/console.
  Would love to get your suggestions.
  Thanks

Comment: It doesn't solve your problem, but Passenger 5 doesn't support Rails versions before 2.3, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

well this doesn't answer the question completely as to what problem was the cause, but I was able to copy the gems, nginx version, passenger version, from another server running the Rails 2 application and it worked.  Here is a list of the versions of everything:

```
nginx 1.6.2
passenger 4.0.53
```

gems:

```
arel (6.0.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.7.7)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
chunky_png (1.3.3)
crack (0.4.2)
daemon_controller (1.2.0)
drx (0.4.5)
elif (0.1.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
fastthread (1.0.7)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
hike (1.2.3)
hpricot (0.6.164)
htmldoc (0.2.3)
i18n (0.6.11)
image_science (1.2.4)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.8.1)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (1.17.2)
multi_json (1.10.1)
mysql (2.9.1)
netrc (0.9.0)
passenger (4.0.53)
pdfkit (0.6.2)
polyglot (0.3.5)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-cache (1.2)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (4.1.2)
rest-client (1.6.7)
ri_cal (0.8.8)
rqrcode (0.4.2)
rqrcode_png (0.1.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubygems-update (2.4.4)
RubyInline (3.12.3)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
safe_yaml (1.0.4)
sprockets (2.12.3)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.4)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.5.3)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
wkhtmltopdf (0.1.2)
ZenTest (4.11.0)
```

thank you hmallett and everyone else that looked at this

Comment: Just came across this post having the exact same issue you are. Did you actually copy over the files from one server to another, or just compile and/or install those versions to the new server? Thanks.

Comment: imarichardson, I just installed these versions

Comment: Thanks much, @Craig. If I might ask one more question, how did you install Passenger 4.0? I know 5.0 is the only one in the apt repo and can't seem to find anything on installing it. Thanks again.

Comment: Figured it out @Craig. Thanks. If interested, I answered my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37687959/how-to-install-phusion-passenger-4-on-ubuntu-on-apache2-or-nginx/37714242#37714242.