# How to install Phusion Passenger 4 on Ubuntu (on apache2 or nginx)?

Tags: apache, nginx, passenger

While I understand that Passenger 5 is currently the standard, I have a unique use case requiring me to use Passenger 4 while I upgrade a current application. I can't seem to find any particular instructions on how to install Passenger 4 from the Passenger site. I also cannot seem to find any apt repositories with Passenger 4 either.

Are there any resources available for doing this? And can this be done via apt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the answer in [this old blog article from Phusion](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/03/08/passenger-4-apt-repository-now-available/).

The Passenger Phusion repo can only hold one version of the distro (now it holds version 5). So, you need to set the repo location in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list (on Ubuntu) to use the specified string in the [blog article](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/03/08/passenger-4-apt-repository-now-available/). Once you do this when [installing Passenger on the server](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/apache/install/oss/trusty/) you will pull in the Passenger 4 repo instead of the Passenger 5 repo.

The following additional points will also help in the installation:

- To get the VirtualHost (via Passenger 4 on Apache) to run a specific version of ruby by way of RVM, [this article was helpful to have](http://terratakashi.logdown.com/posts/190823-use-different-rvm-gemset-for-rails-app-on-apache-server).
- Next, if you have to use a ruby version earlier than 2.0, you may get a problem ["undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349869/undefined-method-source-index-for-gemmodule-nomethoderror). If so use [this to update your gemset to resolve the issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349869/undefined-method-source-index-for-gemmodule-nomethoderror)